# Span Text is True then Radio button checked otherwise unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please Read this problem carefully.

I want the checkbox value checked when the span text is "True" on pageLoad.
the below example works perfectly on radio button click then span value goes to "true" or "false".

**Code**

```js
$('table').on('change', ':radio', function () {
    $(this).next('span').text('True').closest('td')
           .siblings().find('span').text('False');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td> <input  type='radio' name='attandance' ><span>False</span></td>
<td> <input  type='radio' name='attandance' ><span>False</span></td>
<td> <input  type='radio' name='attandance' ><span>False</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want if the span value is true then the radio button automatically checked.
[Here is Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci5oG.jpg)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('table')
  .on('change', ':radio', function () {
    $(this).next('label').text('True').closest('td')
           .siblings().find('label').text('False');
  })
  .find('label').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase() === 'true';
  }).closest('td').find('input').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td> <input type='radio' name='attandance' id="opt1"><label for="opt1">False</label></td>
<td> <input type='radio' name='attandance' id="opt2"><label for="opt2">True</label></td>
<td> <input type='radio' name='attandance' id="opt3"><label for="opt3">False</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I changed `span` to `label`, too, because it's a good practice. But the essence is: find the label/span, check the text, and go up a level to find and change the `input`.

Answer (score 0):

@faizan as i can see you have the function ready for onchange & you just need values to be changed on page/document load.

I suggest you can use `$(document).ready()` function.

Below `$(document).ready()` function will automatically set radio button checked when there will be a true value found.

```js
      $('table').on('change', ':radio', function () {
            $(this).next('span').text('True').closest('td')
                   .siblings().find('span').text('False');
        });

// Page load event to checked the true value 
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("table td").each(function(i, obj){
        var value = $(obj).find("span").text();
        
        if(value === "True"){
          $(obj).find("input[type='radio']").prop("checked",true);
        }
      })
    })
```

```html
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td> <input  type='radio' name='attandance' ><span>False</span></td>
        <td> <input  type='radio' name='attandance' ><span>True</span></td>
        <td> <input  type='radio' name='attandance' ><span>False</span></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

And I would suggest you to use a particular Id in table which will make easier for jQuery to select a particular table in a page.

```
 <table id="tblAttendance">
```